# dompdf stopped rendering after a year

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

On a php application I have created, I use DOMPDF to generate some pdf files. although it was working perfectly for over a year, it suddenly stopped rendering!! Any ideas on what might have caused it? I am still waiting for the error logs

---

Got the logs, but they are useless. It says "Script timed out before returning headers"

---

Edit 2: Each page has 3 images. A logo which is an image on my server, a qrcode which uses google's apis and a barcode generated on my server too. When I removed the images it managed to render properly. But the whole point in these pdfs is to give the qr/barcode!

Comment: Dompdf doesn't use a license or anything like that so it shouldn't stop working unless something on your system has changed. You'll need to provide more info, such as the logs when you get them or any software changes on your server.

Comment: Yes I know. I do not have direct access to that server so I am waiting for logs and updates. It is supposed that no changes were made on the server. I deleted the dompdf's tmp folder as it was full of empty folders but it didn't help. I am waiting for more info. I was just hoping this would be something common

Comment: @BrianS I got the logs, check the edit above...but nothing useful I think

Comment: Just a few questions that might help answer your question. Is your server a VPS or dedicated server or shared hosting? Has anything on the server changed, like PHP version? What is the content you are feeding into DOMPDF, has that changed or are there lots of errors being dumped into the HTML?

Comment: Add error reporting to your script and the generating script might report some errors that can be of use to you. `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: If the script timed out you should be able to get more information from PHP about where it timed out. Changing the error reporting level should help. Are you using dompdf's `stream` method? If so one thing you might try is calling `exit();` right afterwards.

Comment: @BrianS - Thanks for the hint. I will try it, although it gets stuck at the "$this->pdf->render();" line. The stream is right after that and it does not reach there.

Comment: If it's getting stuck there then the calling `exit()` probably won't help. Sounds like maybe a problem with an element exceeding the page size, which can be problematic for dompdf (especially with [tables](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/98)).

Comment: @BrianS I removed all the tables and I am using divs now. Still the same problem. When I remove the 2 of the three images in each page it renders... But why would it work for a year and suddenly stop?

Comment: That I couldn't say. Has anything else about your system changed? Is this document similar to ones you've rendered in the past? Since we don't have a solution and the comment thread is running long is might be better to move the [dompdf support](http://groups.google.com/group/dompdf) form or SO chat.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. It looks like the client's API changed some texts and the size increased moving the two images I had out of the page...this caused dompdf to timeout and crash. After changing the position of the images and saved some space everything works fine.